# Why does Siri say 座布団１枚お願いします when I told him he is an interesting person?

Tags: expressions, set-phrases

I use Siri to practice my Japanese. I basically say random things to him and see how he responds. (I know this is not even close to effective, don't judge me...)

Today I said to Siri that he is an interesting person:

> Siriさんは面白い人ですね

And he responds with this really weird sentence:

> [座布団]{ざぶとん}１枚お願いします

I guessed that 座布団 refers those cushions that people sit on (and Google Translate proved me right). So the sentence would mean something like:

> a cushion, please!

It makes no sense! What is Siri saying? Is this like a meme or something?

I searched the phrase on the web but all the results are all in Japanese which I can't fully understand...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It comes from a show called 笑点｛しょうてん｝where whenever someone says something interesting, they're given a 座布団｛ざぶとん｝ or mat to sit on.

[Reference](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1020703490)

Comment: In the new 逆転裁判6 game, one of the characters is a rakugo and sits at the witness bench of the courtroom atop about 20 purple zabutons. (And later says 座布団一枚！during testimony). I guess this is a pun on both rakugo and the 笑点 TV show.